# Why I cannot get the data from body in request method

Tags: node.js, api

I try to get the JSON data from a GET request and I can see the information from body in request. How can I get the data?

Currently use NodeJs, basic in JavaScript.

```
var definedURL="https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x6a750d255416483bec1a31ca7050c6dac4263b57&page=1&offset=100&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken";
var request = require('request') 

var information=[];
request({ 
    url: definedURL, 
    json: true 
}, function (error, response, body) { 

if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    //console.log(body.result[0]);
    information.push(body.result[0]);
} 
});
console.log(information);
```

I expect after this I will see the contain of result coming out, but now it still shows [].

Comment: refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/7688842 regarding GET requests.

Comment: You can get the body in request callback,  `//console.log(body.result[0]);` uncomment this line.

Comment: simply because body in GET method is ignored. use POST method instead to use the body. You can still play around with the url's query string as well with POST method while accessing the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are making asynchronous request. Asynchronous action will get completed after the main thread execution.

`console.log(information) // execute before your call`

You need to wait for the request call to get completed and received data get pushed to `information`

There can be two ways to do this -

**Async/Await**-  [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
var definedURL="https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x6a750d255416483bec1a31ca7050c6dac4263b57&page=1&offset=100&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken";
var request = require('request') 

var information=[];

async () => {
  await request({ 
      url: definedURL, 
      json: true 
  }, function (error, response, body) { 

      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          //console.log(body.result[0]);
          information.push(body.result[0]);
      } 
  });
  console.log(information)
}();
```

**Promise** [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
var definedURL="https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x6a750d255416483bec1a31ca7050c6dac4263b57&page=1&offset=100&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken";
var request = require('request') 

var information=[];
var Promise  = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  request({ 
      url: definedURL, 
      json: true 
  }, function (error, response, body) { 
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            //console.log(body.result[0]);
            information.push(body.result[0]);
            resolve()
        } 
  });
})

Promise.then(() => {
    console.log(information)
})
```